# Add some value to input that servers as a placeholder when user changes it and keep it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In fact, this is not going to serve like a real value, just for the decoration purposes, functioning like a placeholder.

I wrote this code, with only the $ sign it works fine, but I can't modify it, for example, so as it could be like "From $" or any other combination.

[Codepen link to demostrate](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/bNRyZw)

```
function priceInputPlaceholder(){
    $( 'input' ).on('input', function() {
            $( this ).val( function( index, val ) {
                return (val[0] == "$" || !val) ? val : "$" + val;
            });
        });
    }

 priceInputPlaceholder();
```

As you see, it, no matter what, always keeps the dollar sign before the value. No matter how many times I click or what I input there.

However, if I modify it like this: [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/azwrMa)

```
function priceInputPlaceholder(){
    $( 'input' ).on('input', function() {
            $( this ).val( function( index, val ) {
                return (val[0] == "From$" || !val) ? val : "From$" + val;
            });
        });
    }

 priceInputPlaceholder();
```

It is just adding "From$" on each keypress. Which is really unclear to me.

I thought maybe the issue is with the `val` array, I tried different combination with indexes inside, but they didn't work.

Comment: I'd simply have another HTML element to the left of the input. See: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether `From$` exists in the value so check whether the string exists by using [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) like

```js
function priceInputPlaceholder() {
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).val(function(index, val) {
      return (!val || val.indexOf("From$") > -1) ? val : "From$" + val;
    });
  });
}

priceInputPlaceholder();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="From$" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are comparing val[0] == "From$", which will always be false. val[0] will only match the first character.

Here is an example that demonstrates how you could solve this problem:

```
function priceInputPlaceholder(){
$( 'input' ).on('input', function() {
        $( this ).val( function( index, val ) {
            return ((val[0] == "F" && 
                     val[1] == "r" && 
                     val[2] == "o" && 
                     val[3] == "m" && 
                     val[4] == "$") || !val) ? val : "From$" + val;
        });
    });
}

priceInputPlaceholder();
```

Comment: thank you for your effort but your solution is less elegant than Arun's :)